# Using a javascript variable from a data-attribute as a key for a multidimensional JSON array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let's say that I have a uni dimensional dataset like this:

```
let data = {"adam":19,"james":22,"john":24}
```

and some HTML like this

```
  <span id="person" data-path="adam">
```

I can fun a function like this to get the age for the record `adam` and then inset it into the element with the `id` of `person`

```
let person = document.getElementById('person')
let name = person.dataset.path
let age = data[path]
person.innerHTML = age
```

I understand that we can use dot (`.`) within a data-attribute, but I can not use a similar technique as above, where I use a data-attribute as a key to access a multidimensional dataset.

For example, let's say this is my dataset

```
let multi =    {
        "adam": {
            "age": 19,
            "color": "red"
        }
    }
```

and my HTML is

```
  <span id="person" data-path="adam.age">
```

I would expect to be able to access the value of `"age"` seeing as I can manually access it as `multi.adam.age` but this does not work.

Does anyone know why using a `.` from a variable to access multidimensional dataset does not work?

Comment: because it is looking for `let multi = { "adam.age": 19`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path

Comment: 1) It's not a "multi-dimensional JSON array", it's an object. 2) _"I would expect"_... why would you expect that result? `data-path="adam.age"` is a _string_.

Answer (score 1):

When you get `data-attribute` value as `adam.age` then It will look for `"adam.age"` property in the `multi` object which doesn't exist, so it gives `undefined`

Alternatively, you can achieve this using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let multi = {
  "adam": {
    "age": 19,
    "color": "red"
  }
}

let person = document.getElementById('person')
let name = person.dataset.path
let age = name.split(".").reduce((acc, curr) => acc[curr], multi)
console.log(age);
person.innerHTML = age
```

```html
<span id="person" data-path="adam.age">
```